# Create stock.location automatically - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this method which inherits from `stock.location` on `fleet.vehicle` model from module `fleet`:

```
class fleet_vehicle(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'fleet.vehicle'

    location_id = fields.Many2one("stock.location", string="Almacén Origen", store=True)
```

So, this grings model `stock.location` into `fleet.vehicle` model, this is my view:

```
    <record model='ir.ui.view' id='fleet_vehicle_form'>
        <field name="name">fleet.vehicle.form</field>
        <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref='fleet.fleet_vehicle_form'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//form/sheet/group" position="after">
                <group string="Almacén correspondiente" col="2">
                <field name="location_id"/>
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

So far, so good, now, I've been asked to create one location every time a new vehicle is added into the database, from `fleet.vehicle` form.

As You can see, I have added the model and field to add the location already, but,  how can this location be created every time a new vehicle is saved?

For example, I create the vehicle `Opel/Astra`, this should create a new location called `Opel/Astra` in the system, automatically, I know how to declare default locations, source and destination ones, for example like this:

```
def _static_location(self):
    return self.env.ref('fleet_stock.location_stock')
```

Then call the function from field, like:

```
    x_location_dest_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string=u'Ubicacion Destino de Productos', required=True,
                                    readonly=False, default=_static_location,
                                    help="Location where the system will look for components.")
```

Which of course is declared on a xml file in `data` folder, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data noupdate="1">
<record id="location_stock" model="stock.location">
    <field name="name">ReparacionUnidades</field>
    <field name="location_id" ref="stock.stock_location_locations_virtual"/>
    <field name="usage">production</field>
    <field name="company_id"></field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Now, how can I "default" this behaviour, not to a an already existent location, but to create a new one depending on the `fleet.vehicle` car name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guess, you need to create new stock.location based on car name.
But I'm confused why did you use data file in your examples.

What you have to do: search for `stock.location` which has `fleet.vehicle` name already. If search succeeded set `location_id`. If not create new `stock.location` and assign to `location_id`. I don't see problem here, why you are not able to do this by your own?

Because I don't know how your system works I can't give you code. But you need `onchange` method on `location_id`. If name is set then you can go and search for `stock.location` or create and assign new one.

Comment: Hi, sorry it was just an example, yeah, something like that is what I need, but I don't know how to approach it on v9 API, could You point me to some example?

Comment: I'm sure you are able to write by yourself. Make `@api.onchange('car_name')` then in function write: `self.env['stock.location'].create({'name': self.car_name})` this for creation stock location, but before that you must search it: `self.env['stock.location'].search([('name', '=', self.car_name)])`. Its very trivial I think